# Android icon missing when uploading to playstore

Tags: java, android

When I install my application it's working fine, the icon is displayed and have no issues, however when installing the application on the device from the apk it does not show the application name, it shows the package with no icon, when uploading to playstore it gives me an error stating I should add an icon to the application.

This use to work until recently.
ic_launcher icon file does exist.

my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.package">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.package.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.package.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.package.NotificationsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoti"></activity>

        <service android:name="com.my.package.FirebaseService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.my.package.FirebaseToken">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="keyhere" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

I removed the > after MultiDexApplication. Figured the android:icon was greyed out and hence not working.

Thanks.